# lifecycle-process: app crash when importing dependency

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, androidx-lifecycle

I was using lifecycle extensions library for a while, but I notice that when updating from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0 the app crash systematically when opening a draggable view. Since the library has been reworked, and the code I use is now in lifecycle-process. But even with the latest alpha version (2.3.0-alpha07) the crash is here. The crash only occurs on API 29 and above.

I've a legacy code for a draggable view that creates a fragment transaction on the pre-draw of the Activity. If I don't add the lib dependency the Fragment is Resumed on the Activity pre-draw, when I add the lib dependency (even if no code used) the Fragment is only Initialized on the Activity pre-draw.

I understand the lib ContentProvider starts even if I don't need it, but I'm not sure what is causing this Fragment lifecycle change. I found that the ReportFragment has worrying comments and a API>=29 check, so if you can help on that, thanks!

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment.java;l=41

PS: If I use commitNow instead of commit in my DraggingView, I don't see the crash anymore. But I want to understand that to be sure it's ok in the rest of my app.

PS2: I tried to create a SSCCE but I cannot reproduce the issue outside of my app, and I can't share my entire app :/

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: What is the crash? Exception stack trace??

Comment: Please post crash stack trace and relevant code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321223/unable-to-get-provider-androidx-startup-initializationprovider)